# Running os.system commands with PyInstaller won't work even if I use the --add-data command to add the executable to the final executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller

As the title said. My code contains a line like this:

```py
os.system('aria2c -x 16 -s 16 example.com')
```

and I included the executable required in the `--add-data` command when using PyInstaller to compile the executable with `--onefile`, but until this part, it shows up something like this, which I assume that the executable isn't properly bundled:

```
'aria2c' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Anything to modify on the spec file, or any fixes?